# Deploying symfony 3 project

Tags: symfony, deployment, ftp

I'm trying to deploy my symfony project but i still have this error .
Any help plz !!

Error =>"
403 - Forbidden Error
You are not allowed to access this address. 
If the error persists, please contact the website webmaster.
Common reasons for this error are:

Incorrect file/directory permissions: Below 644.
In order files to be read by the webserver, their permissions have to be equal or above 644. You can update file permissions with a FTP client or through cPanel's File Manager.

Restrictive Apache directives inside .htaccess file.
There are two Apache directives which can cause this error - 'Deny from' and 'Options -Indexes'. "

[Screenshot  deployment error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CrP7Z.png)

Comment: Have you try server run from symfony?  if it works, the problem probably come from your apache config, try to fix it and dont forget to restart apache everytime

Comment: I can not try server run because i've just copied files manually via FileZilla , i havnt any acces to the server

Comment: Apparently this 403 is thrown because your IP is'nt  whitelisted, check app*.php files maybe only 127.0.0.1 is  allowed